# How to set section titles to Arial and main text to CMU Serif, without disabling the functions of \textit{}, \textbf{} etc

Tags: fonts

I'm writing my thesis, and I want all the section headings to be in Arial and the body text to be in CMU Serif. I'm using `report` as documentclass and XeLaTeX to compile the document. I'm not a pro at using overleaf, so please bear with me (I'm not sure how much code you need to see to help me). I tried to do it in the following way:

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}

\setromanfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{Arial}
```

This works fine, but the issue is that suddenly the `\textit{}`, `\textbf{}` and so on doesn't work. Then I tried google it, and found someone saying that I should load the package `\usepackage{lmodern}`, which made the `\textit{}`, `\textbf{}` etc. work, but it also changed the font of the section headings to another sans serif font.

I'm using a thesis template from my university, so I don't understand all the code. I can also see that I have loaded this package: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` - maybe it clashes with the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`? But I have no idea what they mean.. And nothing seems to happen when I remove one or the other..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Since you're loading the `fontspec` package, you shouldn't load either the `inputenc` or the `fontenc` package. Please tell us whether you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document.

Comment: Please can you show a minimal working example instead of code snippets only. We need such a MWE to reproduce your problem and to find and test ideas for a solution.

Comment: Okay, so I tried to make a minimal working example, but here it actually works fine.. And I can't find the difference between the two.. But it still doesn't work in my thesis document.

Comment: Okay, so I went through all the document packages and removed them with % one by one. And I found that the \usepackage{fourier} was the one that disabled the italic and bold functions.. I also have no idea what this package is for, so I hope it doesn't interfere with other functions, that I have now removed it.